# CKEditor - not submit data in in post

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have html code in my form:

```
<textarea name="page_desc" class="form-control" id="page_desc" placeholder="Page Description" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Following is my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace('page_desc');
    });
```

It loads the ckeditor in form, but when I submit the form it doesn't pass the data in page_desc field. I checked in post data. page_desc field is blank. Then I tried this:

```
    CKEDITOR.instances.page_desc.on('blur', function(e) { 
        console.log(e); //see screenshot below what it returns
        console.log(document.getElementById('page_desc').value);//it is blank
    });
```

In console I get this:
[image]

`data` is `undefined` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor doesn't provide data like this. You have to use the code as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.page_desc.getData();
```

And have to submit the data by using custom [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Comment: Yes, its working. But why I need to get Data and set Data manually? shouldn't my textarea autopopulate with the value entered in ckeditor automatically?

Comment: CKEditor does create its own dom when you replace the element using CKEDITOR.replace. So real element doesn't has any data.

Comment: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_inline.html this is a reference doc have a look.